# How can I match part of a string to a list in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need to create a google sheet that I can enter a string of text which will then crosscheck against a list of about 800 keywords/phrases and if there is a match, I need it to set a true flag on the keyword/phrase it matches on. For example:

```
 string: hihowareyou doing

 List:
 Example = False
 Example = False
 Example = False
 Example = False
 Example = False
 hi      = True
 Example = False
 Example = False
 are     = True
 Example = False
 Example = False
```

Is this possible and can someone tell me how to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming text in B1 and list in A2 etc then in B2:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(B$1,A2:A))
```

For case insensitivity you might force  text and list elements into the same case, for example:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(lower(B$1),lower(A2:A)))
```

One way to restrict the cells visibly populated in ColumnB:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A)=0,"",REGEXMATCH(lower(B$1),lower(A2:A))))
```

Another way (frees up the "empty" cells"):

```
=array_constrain(ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(lower(B$1),lower(A2:A))),counta(A:A),1)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed thank you! Is there a way to make it case-insensitive? Also, is there a way to set a range for the true or false flags to stop? it sets the true flag on every cell in the B column after the end of my word list. Thank you very much!